# проблема с командой django 'makemigrations''

Tags: python, django

при попытке подключение mysql к django, когда пишу команду 'makemigrations' выводит ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 166, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 283, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Радмир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 166, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>)
```

mysqlclient и mysqlserver установлен

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djang',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '123321',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите Ваш код обращения к БД и код моделей(и)

Comment: у меня их нет у меня проблемы с подключением

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос: известно ли Вам предназначение команды `makemigrations`?

Comment: да, к чему такой вопрос?

Comment: Вы говорите, что у Вас нет моделей, однако Вы пытаетесь подготовить  миграцию. Из чего Вы хотите её сделать без единой модели?

Comment: я просто создал проект и сразу захотел подключить mysql.

Comment: Это так не работает. БД подключается автоматически в те моменты, когда к ней необходимо обратиться, а команда `makemigrations` подготавливает миграцию из Ваших моделей. Вследствие чего приходим к выводу, что на мой второй комментарий скорее стоило ответить отрицательно.

Comment: с моделями тоже самая ошибка

Comment: покажите модель

Comment: class siteinfo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926091/django-mysqlclient-backend-produces-django-db-utils-operationalerror-2059-nu посмотрите здесь. Очень похожий вопрос.

Comment: Находил попробовал не получилось

Comment: а щяс сработало

Comment: Что Вы поменяли в итоге?

Comment: я просто не правильно понял когда сам нашёл, а со второго раза понял

Comment: Помог-таки мой комментарий, обращайтесь.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно изменить шифровку на 
mysql_native_password

```
alter user 'root'@localhost identified with mysql_native_password by '82134'
```